# How to sort productcollection by category and sku?

Tags: magento

I'm using a custom extension for Magento, with the following code to show a list of products.
At the moment, products are sorted by SKU, but I would like to sort these products by category.

I've tried with replacing addAttributeToSelect with addCategoryFilter($category), but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have a clue which code to add to this example to sort by category at first, and within this category by SKU ?

```
    $this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()

        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$_arrayOfProductIds))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->setOrder('sku', 'asc')->load();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think products know what categories they're in so you will have to get the categories first and then pull their products collection. I believe it's $category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(5) for example. Then $products = $category->getProductCollection();

Comment: Also, I always go to this page first for collections-related questions: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/using_collections_in_magento

Comment: Products know what categories they're in. But each product can belong to unlimited number of categories, so I don't understand what you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code.

$this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()

->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$_arrayOfProductIds))

```
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

    ->setOrder('sku', 'asc')->load();
```